# how to correctly install dotnet cli on Windows 10 x64

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, command-line-interface

Im trying to migrate my aspnet core RC1 project to RC2.

I have installed preview 1 (DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1) and then Preview 2 (dotnet-dev-win-x64.latest). But the When I did dotnet restore, the assemblies were not resolving in the project.json file.

So what I did, I've uninstall everything (Preview 1 and 2)  then installed Preview 1 again. But now when I try to run dotnet --info, it gives the below error.

`Failed to load the dll from [], HRESULT: 0x80070057`

I tried removing temp files but did not work. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

> Im trying to migrate my aspnet core RC1 project to RC2.

The best way is create new/clean project after installing RC2 and move your code to this new project (or at least use/compare `project.json` from this new).

In my case it's take me 3-4h and I have no problems after.

> I have installed preview 1 (DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1) and then Preview 2 (dotnet-dev-win-x64.latest). But the When I did dotnet restore, the assemblies were not resolving in the project.json file.
>
> So what I did, I've uninstall everything (Preview 1 and 2) then installed Preview 1 again. But now when I try to run dotnet --info, it gives the below error.

I'm still using RC2/Tools Preview 1, however I heard about known issues with VS 2015 U3 and Tooling Preview 2.

*(btw: which version of VS you are using?)*

Solution in that case is reinstalling `VC++ Redistributable` after installing Tooling Preview2.

Read more here:

- [Visual Studio 2015 Tooling Preview 2 now available](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/192)
- [Discussion for pre-release build 'Nightly - 6/7/16'](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/577)
- [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 RC Known Issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3-rc)

If this not help you, then try following steps:

- Uninstall all ASP.NET Core SDK RC1, RC2, tooling preview 1, preview 2...
- Clean up your folders manually (Userfolder\Appdata, ProgramData, ProgramFiles (both), Temp),
- Check if you have installed .NET targeting packs v4.5.1 and v4.6.1 - if not, install them in order form [Targeting .NET Platforms](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html).
- Install stable version of SDK and tools form [.NET Core Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I ended up installing windows again to my development pc. Then I've installed RC2 Preview1 and Created a new Project and added all my code. That works. Im using VS 2015 Update2. Also I saw Preview 2 build is failing for Windows x64 in Github. Anyways. Creating a fresh project and migrate your code is the safest and easiest way. But I dont now who this RC2 works with xUnit . All my tests are in Xunit.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using xUnit so I can't advice, sorry.

Comment: Thank fine. Thanks.